# Getting only single id's data from database

Tags: php, mysqli, xampp

Hi i am fetching data from data base but this is showing only id no. 1 data only when i click on other items.This is the link of id no. 2 but showing the data of id no 1.

http://localhost/ecom/details.php?item_title=Sample2&id=2

```
 if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

                          $id = isset($_GET['id']);

                           $sql = "SELECT * FROM men_watches WHERE id = '$id' ";

                           $run = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                                if (false === $run) {
                                        echo mysql_error();
                                    }  

                           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
                          $discounted_price = $row['item_price'] - $row['item_discount'];

                      echo "
                           <div class='col-md-6'>
                           <h3 class='pp-title'>$row[item_title]</h3>
                           <img src='$row[item_image]' class='img-responsive' >
                           <div class='bottom'>

                           <div class='pull-right cutted-price text-muted'><del>$ $row[item_price]</del></div>
                           <div class='clearfix'></div>
                           <div class='pull-right disscounted-price'>$$discounted_price</div>
                           </div>
                           <h4 class='pp-dsc-title'>Description</h4>
                           <div class='pp-dsc-detail'>$row[item_description]</div>
                           </div> 

                   ";
                  }
               }else {
                    echo "The request is not working";
                }    
            ?>
```

This is the code i am using to fetch the data from database.I am new in programming guys so please help me

Comment: You assign the bool value of `isset` to `$id`. try `$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `$id = isset($_GET['id']);` => $id setting to 1

Change

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']);
```

To

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 0;
```